# Entity Framework Leaving Orphan Objects On Delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am removing an object from the table using Entity Framework.

```
public class Application {
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public FundingInfo FundingInfo { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class FundingInfo {
    public long FundingInfoId { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

When I delete the application, it leaves the FundingInfo entry orphaned. When creating the migration the PK (FundingInfoId) that is created on the Application is set to `onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict` I changed this to be set to `onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade` and it still leaves this entry in Funding Info.

How do I get Entity to cascade on delete for a 1 to 1 object? I do want the FundingInfo object in Application to be able to be null... but if it is not null when deleting the object, it should also delete the FundingInfo object as well?

Obviously I can manually delete it, but this is one of many 1 to 1 objects that are being orphaned and I would like to be able to avoid traversing the object with a bunch of loops.

Comment: Add the code how you setup the relation between the two classes in EF. BTW there are lots of examples/tutorials out in the web on how to configure EF relations and the best option is to use the EF-FluentAPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it required and cascade deletion will be enabled.

```
public class Application {
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public FundingInfo FundingInfo { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class FundingInfo {
    public long FundingInfoId { get; set; }
    ....
}
```